# What's the meaning of "I casually drink alcohol" and "I socially drink alcohol"

Tags: meaning

If I said,

> I casually drink alcohol

or

> I socially drink alcohol

What would you think about how often I drink?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "casual drinker" would be someone who occasionally has up to a few drinks (enough to "get buzzed", i.e. to know that you are intoxicated, but not so much that you become seriously impaired).  I would expect a casual drinker to enjoy a couple of beers after a particularly tough workday, or to have a glass of wine with dinner occasionally.

A "social drinker" would be someone who generally drinks in the company of their friends; either you have friends over and serve alcohol, or you go over to a friend's house and drink the alcohol they serve, or you all go out to a bar together.

You can be a social drinker who becomes excessively intoxicated or who never has more than one drink, or you can be a casual drinker who does not drink socially, or who only drinks when friends are over; the phrases are not necessarily points along the same spectrum.  (One deals with how much alcohol you consume at a time, the other with what situations in which you tend to consume.)

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer *I drink alcohol socially* as your sentence form doesn't sound right to me, and if we add *only*, it makes the sentence clearer as one could say: *I drink alcohol socially and at every other opportunity for a drink.*

I have never heard of drinking casually. I only drink casually suggests that when you drink alcohol you stand there looking really cool and not like an unrelaxed misfit in the corner of the room.
 I go along with the answer where a person could be described as a casual drinker, which in my definition is not very much.

*I only drink socially implies* that it is not *habitually*, i.e., you drink at social occasions with company and not routinely e.g., every weekend or always after work.

But we could even think that *I only drink alcohol socially* means that when I drink I'm sociable and don't get totally pissed and insult everyone in the room.

Answer (score 1):

Casually might be drinking on your own infrequently *(at home alone)*
Socially would be only with a group of people or on a date or at a bar

Answer (score 1):

"socially" tells me the situations in which you drink, that you tend to (or only) drink in company of other drinkers.

"casually" tells me the frequency with which you drink, lower than I might expect otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Every friday/saturday night.

Maybe a glass of wine each night.

Beers after work.